# Proving an existence of triple set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Pair set axiom guarantees that from sets $A$, $B$, there exists a set $\{A, B\}$. But how to prove from sets $A$, $B$, $C$, there exists a set $\{A, B, C\}$? Is the following method correct? If so, can the method be applied to any number of sets(e.g., from $A$, $B$, $C$, ..., $K$ to $\{A, B, C, ..., K\}$)? 
Take $\{A, B\}$ and $\{C\}$ by pair set axiom and again take $\{\{A, B\}, \{C\}\}$ by pair set axiom then get $\{A, B, C\}$ from arbitrary union axiom.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You can genralize this to a finite number of sets, using induction(In the meta-theory, I guess)